R VGAM (vglm) Some elements in the working weights variable 'wz' are not finite
I'm trying to fit a beta-binomial function with vglm from the VGAM library, calling it from rpy2:
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeWarning

BETABIN_params = robjects.r('''
    function (x, y){
        suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(VGAM))
        fit = invisible(vglm(cbind(x,y) ~ 1, betabinomialff, trace = FALSE))
        alpha <- Coef(fit)[[1]]
        beta <- Coef(fit)[[2]]
        return(c(alpha,beta))
    }
    ''')

# Sample sites from each cell types
Alt_BC = [int(x[2]) for x in CCounts] #list of 500k int from 0 to ~10
Ref_BC = [int(x[3]) for x in CCounts] #list of 500k int from 10 to ~1000

PARAMS2 = BETABIN_params(robjects.IntVector(Alt_BC), robjects.IntVector(Ref_BC)) #works
alpha2 = float(tuple(PARAMS2)[0])
beta2 = float(tuple(PARAMS2)[1])

Alt_CC = [int(x[0]) for x in CCounts] <-list of 500k int from 0 to ~10
Ref_CC = [int(x[1]) for x in CCounts] <-list of 500k int from 5 to ~100

PARAMS = BETABIN_params(robjects.IntVector(Alt_CC), robjects.IntVector(Ref_CC)) #doesn't work
alpha1 = float(tuple(PARAMS)[0])
beta1 = float(tuple(PARAMS)[1])

It worked with multiple datasets, but one in particular gave me the title error, only for the CC counts:
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in checkwz(wz, M = M, trace = trace, wzepsilon = control$wzepsilon) :
Some elements in the working weights variable 'wz' are not finite

I tried to investigate the values of Alt_CC and Ref_CC, but it looks fine to me:
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(Alt_CC))
Counter({0: 491237, 1: 3509, 2: 141, 3: 57, 4: 35, 5: 27, 6: 20, 7: 16, 8: 7, 10: 4, 11: 4, 14: 2, 9: 1, 12: 1})
print(Counter(Ref_CC))
Counter({5: 204279, 6: 120809, 7: 68706, 8: 39239, 9: 23460, 10: 14224, 11: 8595, 12: 5395, 13: 3404, 14: 2231, 15: 1444, 16: 990, 17: 572, 18: 357, 19: 222, 20: 158, 71: 86, 69: 77, 21: 70, 70: 64, 67: 52, 72: 49, 22: 49, 68: 41, 73: 34, 114: 30, 23: 29, 113: 28, 66: 24, 116: 24, 115: 22, 64: 20, 74: 18, 24: 17, 109: 17, 111: 17, 65: 16, 112: 16, 107: 11, 108: 11, 117: 10, 110: 9, 25: 8, 26: 8, 62: 7, 75: 7, 63: 6, 60: 6, 106: 6, 29: 5, 55: 4, 53: 4, 56: 4, 47: 4, 61: 4, 58: 3, 51: 3, 43: 3, 35: 3, 48: 3, 103: 3, 104: 3, 118: 3, 27: 3, 102: 3, 57: 2, 54: 2, 49: 2, 59: 2, 36: 2, 45: 2, 37: 2, 50: 2, 100: 2, 30: 2, 105: 2, 31: 2, 101: 2, 33: 1, 41: 1, 38: 1, 32: 1, 84: 1, 83: 1})

For reference, the working values:
print(Counter(Alt_BC))
Counter({0: 491237, 1: 2728, 2: 857, 3: 82, 4: 50, 5: 27, 6: 26, 7: 15, 8: 11, 11: 6, 9: 5, 10: 4, 12: 3, 14: 2, 15: 2, 21: 1, 17: 1, 20: 1, 16: 1, 19: 1, 13: 1})
print(Counter(Ref_BC))
Counter({10: 96557, 9: 76671, 12: 59902, 11: 54222, 14: 33350, 8: 32764, 13: 32445, 15: 18979, 16: 18423, 17: 11588, 18: 10844, 7: 9144, 19: 7093, 20: 6370, 21: 4466, 22: 3903, 23: 2857, 24: 2521, 6: 1905, 25: 1783, 26: 1529, 27: 1211, 28: 1016, 29: 805, 30: 646, 31: 516, 32: 455, 33: 371, 5: 363, 34: 279, 35: 239, 36: 216, 37: 160, 38: 122, 39: 122, 40: 71, 42: 56, 43: 55, 41: 53, 44: 52, 45: 38, 47: 21, 46: 17, 52: 12, 49: 10, 48: 10, 50: 9, 51: 8, 56: 6, 1110: 5, 53: 5, 54: 5, 1106: 4, 1276: 4, 1118: 4, 55: 4, 809: 3, 1042: 3, 1078: 3, 1003: 3, 1079: 3, 965: 3, 1005: 3, 1224: 3, 686: 3, 685: 3, 1177: 3, 1008: 3, 1173: 3, 58: 3, 57: 3, 1305: 3, 1001: 2, 1035: 2, 1061: 2, 59: 2, 711: 2, 1124: 2, 724: 2, 953: 2, 266: 2, 1032: 2, 314: 2, 1129: 2, 450: 2, 982: 2, 992: 2, 957: 2, 1211: 2, 1186: 2, 1089: 2, 755: 2, 1067: 2, 1103: 2, 690: 2, 872: 2, 231: 2, 1099: 2, 1025: 2, 506: 2, 1040: 2, 1229: 2, 395: 2, 504: 2, 246: 2, 1028: 2, 327: 2, 1047: 2, 1039: 2, 1037: 2, 1044: 2, 1094: 2, 1117: 2, 62: 2, 1004: 2, 1109: 2, 830: 2, 1303: 2, 1043: 2, 1069: 2, 998: 2, 1199: 2, 1013: 2, 1244: 2, 987: 2, 903: 2, 905: 2, 844: 2, 958: 2, 967: 2, 854: 2, 996: 2, 70: 2, 629: 2, 898: 2, 190: 2, 99: 2, 1074: 2, 3120: 2, 71: 2, 777: 2, 2939: 2, 2516: 2, 1472: 2, 3081: 2, 3272: 2, 2993: 2, 2390: 2, 3405: 2, 3238: 2, 1419: 2, 1164: 2, 1480: 2, 1030: 2, 1329: 2, 1392: 2, 1534: 2, 1415: 2, 1580: 2, 1632: 2, 890: 1, 802: 1, 917: 1, 942: 1, 695: 1, 1057: 1, 597: 1, 825: 1, 983: 1, 748: 1, 390: 1, 688: 1, 463: 1, 563: 1, 820: 1, 382: 1, 593: 1, 758: 1, 621: 1, 585: 1, 410: 1, 988: 1, 756: 1, 1092: 1, 680: 1, 931: 1, 286: 1, 1200: 1, 947: 1, 1123: 1, 797: 1, 1048: 1, 997: 1, 1026: 1, 1038: 1, 959: 1, 860: 1, 744: 1, 264: 1, 851: 1, 1107: 1, 1029: 1, 1233: 1, 1104: 1, 631: 1, 1055: 1, 737: 1, 743: 1, 667: 1, 945: 1, 1115: 1, 1086: 1, 1184: 1, 304: 1, 1176: 1, 144: 1, 775: 1, 939: 1, 778: 1, 1084: 1, 728: 1, 616: 1, 787: 1, 702: 1, 776: 1, 529: 1, 877: 1, 322: 1, 1073: 1, 1100: 1, 233: 1, 966: 1, 1304: 1, 1111: 1, 1096: 1, 904: 1, 848: 1, 949: 1, 1145: 1, 1020: 1, 993: 1, 109: 1, 1027: 1, 822: 1, 514: 1, 1153: 1, 155: 1, 461: 1, 837: 1, 1151: 1, 1068: 1, 105: 1, 221: 1, 277: 1, 64: 1, 1134: 1, 553: 1, 1355: 1, 411: 1, 148: 1, 676: 1, 660: 1, 985: 1, 118: 1, 821: 1, 494: 1, 149: 1, 63: 1, 887: 1, 511: 1, 1135: 1, 1112: 1, 114: 1, 782: 1, 846: 1, 1192: 1, 626: 1, 864: 1, 951: 1, 136: 1, 186: 1, 803: 1, 961: 1, 869: 1, 1162: 1, 856: 1, 107: 1, 1133: 1, 1185: 1, 244: 1, 845: 1, 1165: 1, 1102: 1, 180: 1, 1002: 1, 1178: 1, 427: 1, 172: 1, 914: 1, 338: 1, 762: 1, 1033: 1, 387: 1, 972: 1, 603: 1, 449: 1, 1292: 1, 1050: 1, 913: 1, 841: 1, 910: 1, 823: 1, 1018: 1, 1085: 1, 932: 1, 907: 1, 1169: 1, 689: 1, 1175: 1, 918: 1, 1217: 1, 927: 1, 1236: 1, 124: 1, 800: 1, 672: 1, 500: 1, 143: 1, 754: 1, 567: 1, 130: 1, 873: 1, 891: 1, 1090: 1, 1049: 1, 671: 1, 635: 1, 681: 1, 1031: 1, 723: 1, 1261: 1, 507: 1, 1056: 1, 354: 1, 1138: 1, 784: 1, 617: 1, 1221: 1, 1058: 1, 984: 1, 1083: 1, 185: 1, 1158: 1, 1016: 1, 627: 1, 263: 1, 779: 1, 1077: 1, 1023: 1, 344: 1, 1197: 1, 926: 1, 1127: 1, 92: 1, 1279: 1, 224: 1, 716: 1, 934: 1, 575: 1, 893: 1, 655: 1, 1143: 1, 730: 1, 766: 1, 794: 1, 392: 1, 765: 1, 1190: 1, 360: 1, 999: 1, 151: 1, 471: 1, 95: 1, 764: 1, 909: 1, 521: 1, 1126: 1, 1065: 1, 1010: 1, 604: 1, 963: 1, 1222: 1, 646: 1, 1210: 1, 895: 1, 3048: 1, 3353: 1, 2415: 1, 2889: 1, 2754: 1, 2971: 1, 3666: 1, 2641: 1, 566: 1, 175: 1, 3216: 1, 3028: 1, 2695: 1, 2982: 1, 1996: 1, 899: 1, 2061: 1, 697: 1, 2123: 1, 3091: 1, 3012: 1, 333: 1, 3001: 1, 145: 1, 2551: 1, 1909: 1, 1365: 1, 994: 1, 2267: 1, 3278: 1, 3239: 1, 2208: 1, 3102: 1, 3273: 1, 3241: 1, 3170: 1, 2577: 1, 2579: 1, 2997: 1, 3522: 1, 524: 1, 2700: 1, 2210: 1, 2065: 1, 2836: 1, 3132: 1, 1620: 1, 3880: 1, 2501: 1, 3493: 1, 1420: 1, 3450: 1, 2444: 1, 2904: 1, 3065: 1, 1956: 1, 2309: 1, 2377: 1, 2564: 1, 2775: 1, 1855: 1, 1628: 1, 1717: 1, 3431: 1, 2215: 1, 3095: 1, 2844: 1, 2576: 1, 2194: 1, 522: 1, 3421: 1, 1975: 1, 3281: 1, 2455: 1, 1894: 1, 3038: 1, 2340: 1, 2870: 1, 3308: 1, 2467: 1, 1781: 1, 1761: 1, 3299: 1, 1805: 1, 805: 1, 1634: 1, 3108: 1, 2611: 1, 2869: 1, 2449: 1, 3096: 1, 3765: 1, 3135: 1, 768: 1, 3129: 1, 3088: 1, 3014: 1, 2665: 1, 3178: 1, 990: 1, 2953: 1, 501: 1, 3332: 1, 3011: 1, 1904: 1, 2583: 1, 2228: 1, 3380: 1, 3263: 1, 3186: 1, 3127: 1, 2999: 1, 1785: 1, 3287: 1, 598: 1, 969: 1, 2465: 1, 2633: 1, 3358: 1, 1884: 1, 2954: 1, 3010: 1, 2834: 1, 2809: 1, 675: 1, 2739: 1, 2797: 1, 1816: 1, 3369: 1, 804: 1, 3208: 1, 3187: 1, 3042: 1, 3226: 1, 2893: 1, 3158: 1, 1593: 1, 3006: 1, 2919: 1, 2028: 1, 2570: 1, 3118: 1, 3111: 1, 2217: 1, 2876: 1, 3078: 1, 3185: 1, 1883: 1, 1684: 1, 2924: 1, 2374: 1, 3583: 1, 2321: 1, 2286: 1, 1512: 1, 2078: 1, 2932: 1, 2607: 1, 3504: 1, 1359: 1, 3607: 1, 2201: 1, 2931: 1, 3853: 1, 2905: 1, 3180: 1, 1736: 1, 2796: 1, 1203: 1, 2972: 1, 3039: 1, 2988: 1, 3168: 1, 2890: 1, 2608: 1, 2644: 1, 3284: 1, 2824: 1, 3022: 1, 2896: 1, 2973: 1, 1690: 1, 1328: 1, 2942: 1, 3723: 1, 80: 1, 2554: 1, 3130: 1, 1408: 1, 2556: 1, 2367: 1, 2906: 1, 1046: 1, 3139: 1, 2777: 1, 1613: 1, 1732: 1, 1539: 1, 1266: 1, 1584: 1, 1341: 1, 1317: 1, 1269: 1, 1323: 1, 1880: 1, 1274: 1, 408: 1, 1256: 1, 1440: 1, 1842: 1, 1640: 1, 1064: 1, 1710: 1, 919: 1, 1257: 1, 1833: 1, 1335: 1, 1258: 1, 1364: 1, 1350: 1, 1267: 1, 1393: 1, 1380: 1, 1461: 1, 683: 1, 1618: 1, 1017: 1, 1401: 1, 1340: 1, 350: 1, 1859: 1, 1427: 1, 1507: 1, 1166: 1, 1654: 1, 1476: 1, 1445: 1, 1682: 1, 1564: 1, 1376: 1, 1627: 1, 1572: 1, 1157: 1, 1425: 1, 1066: 1, 516: 1, 1587: 1, 1530: 1, 1839: 1, 1297: 1, 1405: 1, 1452: 1, 1524: 1, 74: 1, 1473: 1, 1372: 1, 1336: 1, 1490: 1, 1246: 1, 1315: 1, 1311: 1, 97: 1, 1571: 1, 1021: 1, 1666: 1, 68: 1, 1450: 1, 1399: 1, 498: 1, 432: 1, 1459: 1, 1071: 1, 1516: 1, 1346: 1, 1396: 1, 1653: 1, 1680: 1, 1529: 1, 1702: 1, 1413: 1, 1394: 1, 1691: 1, 1481: 1, 1488: 1, 656: 1, 1330: 1, 1223: 1, 1439: 1, 1671: 1, 1207: 1, 1479: 1, 795: 1, 1623: 1, 1508: 1, 1294: 1, 1765: 1, 1658: 1, 1484: 1, 362: 1, 1300: 1, 484: 1, 1590: 1, 1556: 1, 1604: 1, 1462: 1, 1525: 1, 404: 1, 1495: 1, 1552: 1, 1454: 1, 1368: 1, 1438: 1, 1485: 1, 1871: 1, 1250: 1, 1528: 1})

I seems to be a input values problem, but maybe my function is wrong? If it is an input problem, how can I filter values without sekwing too much the results?
